# NoMethodError (undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From the frontend sends a request for the establishment of Taska and I receive here such error:

[image]

There is another error on the server:

[image]

In the console itself, I get:

[image]

[image]

```
def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)            // It's 19 line tasks_controller

  if @task.save
    render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task
  else
    render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

and

```
private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

current_user - application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  current_user ||= User.find_by(token: request.headers['Authorization'])
end
```

Scheme table users.

[image]

I am new to all this, what is obvious to you is not known to me, therefore I am here.

Comment: It's so obviously - you cannot find a user, check how you store token in the DB, maybe you need to remove "Basic " from the token string.

Comment: First of all `current_user ||= User.find_by(token: request.headers['Authorization'])` makes no sense really. And apparently, `User.find_by(token: request.headers['Authorization'])` returns `nil` and this is direct cause of your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic do-it-yourself authentication nil error. When setting up an authentication system you should ensure that any action that requires the user to be signed in will bail early and redirect the user to the sign in or if its an API send a header that indicates that the user is not authorized.

```
class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end

class ApplicationController
  # locking everything down makes your app secure by default
  # use skip_before_action :authenticate_user! to allow unauthorized users 
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  rescue_from AuthenticationError, with: :handle_unauthorized_access

  private

  def authenticate_user!
    raise AuthenticationError unless current_user
  end

  def handle_unauthorized_access
    respond_to do |f|
      f.html { redirect_to '/path/to/login', notice: 'Please sign in' }
      f.json { head :unauthorized  }
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Even better is to not reinvent the wheel. Authentication is hard and we all screw it up. Thats why its good to use libraries like Devise or Knock that have tons of eyes reviewing the code.

Comment: Thank you, I will choose your answer. Can you help me how i may use Devise for jwt?

Comment: You can use devise but if you are just doing jwt authentication I would choose Knock as it's a lot lighter and less complex.